# Have h2 inline to h1 and floated to the right in heading

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my h2 to the right side of the header while keeping the same vertical orientation as it is right now, but float right does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<div class="header-bg">

<h1>
Heading
</h1>
<h2>
this is where you write more things
</h2>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-bg {
  background: lightblue;
}
h1, h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  /* border: solid black 1px; */
}

}
h2 {
  /* border: solid black 1px; */
  float: right;
}


ul {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n8xjk4ax/3/

Comment: Hello, you've got a typo `h1, h2 {  [...] } }` you close it two times

Answer (score 2):

First, remove the extraneous `}`, like the comments say.

Now with the `h2` floating, it will no longer be on the same baseline as the `h1`. If you do want them to be, there are several possibilities.

1. Don't float it, but justify-align the items in the container

   ```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
   }

   .header-bg {
     background: lightblue;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: justify;
     -moz-text-align-last: justify;
     text-align-last: justify;
   }

   h1, h2 {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0;
     /* border: solid black 1px; */
   }

   ul {
     clear: both;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background: #333;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
   }

   li {
     float: left;
   }

   li:last-child {
     float: right;
   }

   li a:hover {
     background-color: #111;
     color: white;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="header-bg">
     <h1>
       Heading
     </h1>
     <h2>
       this is where you write more things
     </h2>
   </div>

   <ul>
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. or if you do want to float, the container will also need `overflow:hidden` to account for narrow screens. And you should give the h1 and the h2 the same metrics. Using line-height is most straightforward.

   ```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
   }

   .header-bg {
     background: lightblue;
     overflow:hidden;
   }

   h1, h2 {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 10px;
     line-height: 4rem;
     /* border: solid black 1px; */
   }

   h2 {
     /* border: solid black 1px; */
     float: right;
   }

   ul {
     clear: both;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background: #333;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
   }

   li {
     float: left;
   }

   li:last-child {
     float: right;
   }

   li a:hover {
     background-color: #111;
     color: white;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="header-bg">
     <h1>
       Heading
     </h1>
     <h2>
       this is where you write more things
     </h2>
   </div>

   <ul>
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: this worked beautifully, thank you! Can you clarify why overflow:hidden is necessary to use to keep h2 in the container? I just can't quite grasp the logic behind it. Also, is the line-height used specifically to keep h2 and h1 on the same vertical level?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't explain very well, because I don't understand it entirely myself. I only know that without it, the h2 can overflow out of the header-bg div; i.e. the div doesn't grow to encompass the floating h2, even if the float is cleared after. For me, this is just one of those "that's how it is" things.